# supbrograma ordenar 2 numeros de mayor a menor

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le doy a ejecutar, no me los ordena y me sale en pantalla (3,6)

Comment: Escribe el código para que podamos ver dónde esta el error en vez de poner una imagen, por favor.

Comment: lo intento pero me pone "Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles." y no sé que detalles poner :(

Comment: Describe exáctamente qué quieres conseguir. Por tu código parece que lo que quieres es simplemente ordenar dos números, hay funciones ya específicas para eso, así que explicalo un poco porque igual hay mejores maneras que crearte dos funciones.

Comment: basicamente tengo que hacer un subprograma que me ordene dos numeros de mayor a menor y luego emplearlo para ordenar 3 numeros de mayor a menor. No puedo utilizar funciones ya hechas para ello

Comment: Puedes describir todo eso en la pregunta y así podrá ser localizada por futuros usuarios. Puedes realizar el recorrido para saber cómo preguntar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás pasando los parámetros a tus funciones [por valor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumento_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Paso_por_valor), sin recuperar el valor devuelto por estas.

Si recuperas el valor devuelto por tu función, veras que funciona correctamente como lo muestra el siguiente código

```
num1 = int(input("ingresa primer número: "));
num2 = int(input("ingresa segundo número: "));

def intercambiar(x, y):
  aux = x;
  x = y;
  y = aux;
  return (x, y);

def ordenar2num(x, y):
  if x > y:
    return intercambiar(x, y);
  return (x, y);

numeros = ordenar2num(num1, num2)
print(numeros);
```

Espero haber ayudado. ¡Suerte!

**Update**

Después de observar el refinamiento de la pregunta:

Fijate que ordenar dos números es trivial, pero cuando aumentamos la cantidad de números a ordenar, la complejidad se dispara:

```
num1 = int(input("ingresa primer número: "));
num2 = int(input("ingresa segundo número: "));
num3 = int(input("ingresa tercer numero"));


def ordenar3num(x, y, z):
  if x < y:
    if x < z:
      if (y < z):
        return (x, y, z);
      return (x, z, y);
    return (z, x, y);
  if y < z:
    if x < z:
      return (y, x, z);
    return (y, z, x);
  return (z, y, x);  


numeros = ordenar3num(num1, num2, num3)
print(numeros);
```

Como cada vez que agregamos un nuevo número a ordenar debemos tomar en cuenta este nuevo elemento en cada caso de comparación, quizás debamos pensar en una mejor solución.

Podemos empezar a pensar en el grupo de números ingresados como en una lista, y trabajar sobre la lista en vez de trabajar sobre cada número. Lo cual tiene la ventaja de que nuestra solución se vuelve agnóstica con respecto a la cantidad de números ingresados.

```
num1 = int(input("ingresa primer número: "));
num2 = int(input("ingresa segundo número: "));
num3 = int(input("ingresa tercer numero: "));


def ordenarMejor(nums):
  s = len(nums);
  for i in range(s):
    for j in range(1, s - i):       
        if nums[j-1] > nums[j]:
            (nums[j-1], nums[j]) = (nums[j], nums[j-1])
  return nums;

numeros = ordenarMejor([num1, num2, num3]);
print(numeros);
```

Lo que cumple con la restricción de no usar funciones internas de python. 
Si consideras que debe aplicar alguna otra restricción no dudes en dejar un comentario.

El estudio de los algoritmos de ordenamiento es una rama muy bonita de la ciencia informática, dejo [un enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento) como referencia.

Espero haber ayudado. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Estarías utilizando len y range, por lo que entiendo que así no le valdría, ¿no?

Comment: Puedes tener razón. Pero también es posible que se refiriera a los medios disponibles para ordenar listas en Python, como sort(). De todos modos eso lo puede determinar solo quien hizo la pregunta.

Comment: Entiendo sí, lo que pasa es que acabamos de comenzar con el curso de programacion y no hemos visto todavia los arrays. Igualmente, muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas.

1. Los valores 3 y 6 ya están ordenados de menor a mayor. No es un buen ejemplo para probar si te los está ordenando bien o no :-)
2. Tu función `intercambiar(x,y)` no intercambia directamente los parámetros que le pasas (eso no puede hacerse, pues dentro de la función `x` e `y` son *una copia* de esos parámetros y no son directamente las mismas variables `a` y `b` de la función que las llama). Pero lo has implementado correctamente y además de intercambiar `x` con `y`, *también* retornas la nueva pareja intercambiada.

   Lo que te falta es *recibir* ese resultado en la función que hace uso de `intercambiar()`, es decir:

   ```py
   a, b = intercambiar(a, b)
   ```
3. Para intercambiar variables en python no necesitas escribir una función. Ni siquiera necesitas variables auxiliares como `aux`. Lo siguiente funcionará:

   ```py
   def ordenar2num(a,b):
       if a>b:
          a,b = b,a
       return(a,b)
   ```